# Toshiba satelite laptop takes too long to boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, 64-bit, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satelite C850 (it's close to 2 years since I bought it) and it started some weird behaviour a week ago.

When I start it up it takes too long to show the "Starting Windows" screen. Close to 5 minutes. Before that it shows a black screen with an underscope (_) and nothing else. This screen flashes 4 or 5 times to completely black and then back again to the one with the underscope. I have tried reverting it to factory defaults with the disc provided by the company and I have also done a clear format. The problem still persists.

Apart from that there is no other visible sign, everything runs normally and after the actual boot it's as fast as it always has been. The only visible change is that the right on-board speaker has "ripped" so I have to disable it to properly listen to whatever I want, otherwise there is some undesirable noice. This happened long ago and I believe it's unconnected with the recent behaviour.

OS is Windows 7 64bit Professional edition.

Just to clarify, when I tried to boot from a USB it still displayed that screen before booting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your Toshiba includes the manufacturer diagnostics.  Run them to check for hardware issues.

Boot the system to Safe Mode and see if the problem persists.  If not, it is likely  software creating the delay.

It could also be a service added by software or hardware that is trying to start and then failing.  You can start the system with a Diagnostic Startup by running System Configuration (sysconfig)  and selecting the Diagnostic Startup radio button